# Switching Multiple Constant Current Regulators

Tags: led, constant-current, arduino-uno

I'm looking to setup a grow light system but I'm a bit of a beginner. My aim is to be able to turn on/off two series of LEDs from an Arduino Uno.

At the moment I have two constant current regulators (XL4015E1) for powering the two series of 3W Leds, as seen below.
[image]

I will also connect the Arduino Uno to the same power source using a LM2596S voltage regulator.

I'm currently looking at how I can turn on/off these two series of LEDs. I have some L2203N transistors but I've only seen these on constant voltage LED circuits ([blog](https://www.instructables.com/DIY-Grow-LED-Light-Designing-a-Better-Sun/), [diagram](https://content.instructables.com/ORIG/F1X/WJ4P/JZIOQF3A/F1XWJ4PJZIOQF3A.png?auto=webp&frame=1&width=1024&fit=bounds&md=3f55aa935724835d2b370155e1a563fd)).

Are there any recommendations on how I might approach this? Or is it best to find new constant current drivers with PWM?

Thanks!

[Schematic](https://www.electroschematics.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/9-XL4015-CC-CV-Buck-Module-CKT.jpg) for the regulator board.

Picture of the constant current regulator board:
[image]

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to use a relay to just turn the power on & off?

Comment: @brhans - mainly due to not having a relay to hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without a module schematic it's pretty hard to tell, but I think you could either control the input voltage to the CC module(s) or feed the XL4015 chip a voltage to turn it off.

[image]

Quite likely if you add D2 1N4148 (not optional) to pin 2 of the converter chip you will be able to turn off the XL4015 converter chip with a 3.3V or 5V signal as suggested in the XL4015 chip [datasheet](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1811081616_XLSEMI-XL4015E1_C51661.pdf).

There's plenty of opportunities here to burn various things out, so try at your own risk.

Comment: Thank you Spehro, I'll do some digging into this solution.

Comment: It seems that this is the schematic for the board: https://www.electroschematics.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/9-XL4015-CC-CV-Buck-Module-CKT.jpg. It looks like an LM358 is used to trigger the shutdown feature. I'm just not sure how to trigger it via an Arduino.

Comment: The LM358 works as a low side current measument / current limiting circuit. Just pull input 2 of the LM358 to zero and it should switch off.

Comment: The circuit I suggested should work. Common ground with the Arduino,  control output from GPIO through a diode to pin 2 on the XL4015. The junction between the 270 ohm resistor and LED on the left of your photo would be pin 2 of the XL4015.